# Java concurrency - use which technique to achieve safety?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a list of personId. There are two API calls to update it (add and remove):

```
public void add(String newPersonName) {
    if (personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName) != null) {
        myPersonId.add(personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName)
    } else {
        // get the id from Twitter and add to the list
    }  
    // make an API call to Twitter
 }

public void delete(String personNAme) {
    if (personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName) != null) {
        myPersonId.remove(personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName)
    } else {
        // wrong person name
    }  
    // make an API call to Twitter
}
```

I know there can be concurrency problem. I read about 3 solutions:

1. `synchronized` the method
2. use `Collections.synchronizedlist()`
3. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

I am not sure which one to prefer to prevent the inconsistency.

Comment: I'd recommend synchronizing the list, rather than the method. And I would definitely avoid `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in this scenario, since that's better suited for traversal than mutation.

Comment: From your code snippet, I am not sure how you determined you have a concurrency issue? You can't delete an item unless it was added first and you can't add the same item if it's already in the list. I guess I am trying to understand what's happening concurrently here.

Comment: `myPersonId` can be added to and deleted from simultaneously, if different threads call `add` and `delete` above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) synchronized the method
>
> 2) use Collections.synchronizedlist
>
> 3) CopyOnWriteArrayList ..

All will work, it's a matter of what kind of performance / features you need.

Method #1 and #2 are blocking methods. If you synchronize the methods, you handle concurrency yourself. If you wrap a list in [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29), it handles it for you. (IMHO #2 is safer -- just be sure to use it as the docs say, and don't let *anything* access the raw list that is wrapped inside the synchronizedList.)

[`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is one of those weird things that has use in certain applications. It's a non-blocking quasi-immutable list, namely, if Thread A iterates through the list while Thread B is changing it, Thread A will iterate through a snapshot of the old list. If you need non-blocking performance, and you are rarely writing to the list, but frequently reading from it, then perhaps this is the best one to use.

---

**edit:** There are at least two other options:

4) use [`Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) instead of `ArrayList`; `Vector` implements `List` and is already synchronized. However, it's generally frowned, upon as it's considered an old-school class (was there since Java 1.0!), and should be equivalent to #2.

5) access the `List` serially from only one thread. If you do this, you're guaranteed not to have any concurrency problems with the `List` itself. One way to do this is to use [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) and queue up tasks one-by-one to access the list. This moves the resource contention from your list to the `ExecutorService`; if the tasks are short, it may be fine, but if some are lengthy they may cause others to block longer than desired.

In the end you need to think about concurrency at the application level: thread-safety should be a requirement, and find out how to get the performance you need with the simplest design possible.

---

On a side note, you're calling `personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName)` twice in add() and delete(). This suffers from concurrency problems if another thread modifies personNameIdMap between the two calls in each method. You're better off doing

```
PersonId id = personNameIdMap.get(newPersonName);
if (id != null){
    myPersonId.add(id);
} 
else 
{
    // something else
}
```

Comment: since my operation will be less read and more write . i guess it would be safer to go with option 2.

Comment: be sure to read @TheLQ's answer, it raises some important points

Answer (score 4):

`Collections.synchronizedList` is the easiest to use and probably the best option. It simply wraps the underlying list with `synchronized`. Note that multi-step operations (eg for loop) still need to be synchronized by you.

Some quick things

- Don't synchronize the method unless you really need to - It just locks the *entire* object until the method completes; hardly a desirable effect
- CopyOnWriteArrayList is a very specialized list that most likely you wouldn't want since you have an add method. Its essentially a normal `ArrayList` but each time something is added the whole array is rebuilt, a very expensive task. Its thread safe, but not really the desired result

Comment: I like this answer. It raises two important points: (1) multistep operations need to be synchronized manually, and (2) marking a method as `synchronized` (vs. running a `synchronized(someObj) { }` block) locks the entire object and will compete with any other `synchronized` methods.

Answer (score 3):

1. Synchronized is the old way of working with threads. Avoid it in favor of new idioms mostly expressed in the java.util.concurrent package.
2. See 1.
3. A CopyOnWriteArrayList has fast read and slow writes. If you're making a lot of changes to it, it might start to drag on your performance.

Concurrency isn't about an isolated choice of what mechanism or type to use in a single method. You'll need to think about it from a higher level to understand all of its impacts.

Comment: I wouldn't write off `synchronized` as the "old way" of working with threads -- it's just a blocking approach and you need to know enough about concurrency to use it just as you need to know enough about concurrency to use non-blocking data structures. The only `List<>` in java.util.concurrent (at least in Java 6, I forget if Java 7 adds anything) is `CopyOnWriteArrayList` which is applicable in some situations. Otherwise you're left with a blocking approach.

Comment: `synchronized` is still the main way of doing concurrency, being extremely general.  Everything else (`volatile`, `java.lang.concurrent.atomic`) is more or less a performance optimization applicable and usable only in certain specific cases.  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will always work, but isn't a successful performance optimization unless writes are rare.  Again, it doesn't achieve anything that couldn't have been done with `synchronized`, and you would only use it to try to optimize performance.

Comment: @Jason: I tend to agree with the thinking that synchronizing things yourself is needlessly low level and extremely difficult to get right. It's much better to turn to the higher abstraction levels provided by JDKs 5 and 6 in the java.util.concurrent package. There's very little reason to turn to synchronized in new development when we have so many better and easier ways of doing concurrency. Overall, the point I would emphasize is that doing concurrency right requires a high-level, landscape view, and not a "what kind of concurrency should I use in this method?" approach.

Comment: @Gravity: see previous comment

Comment: @Ryan: good point; +1, because of the "higher level" comment at the end.

Answer (score 2):

In your case from the code that you posted, all 3 ways are acceptable. However, there are some specific characteristics:

#3: This should have the same effect as #2 but may run faster or slower depending on the system and workload.

#1: This way is the most flexible. Only with #1 can you make the the add() and delete() methods more complex. For example, if you need to read or write multiple items in the list, then you cannot use #2 or #3, because some other thread can still see the list being half updated.

Comment: No, #3 is *not* always faster. If you have lots of writes, it will be slow. Please edit your answer or it will be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you making changes to `personNameIdMap` within those methods, or any other data structures access to which should also be synchronized?  If so, it may be easiest to mark the methods as synchronized; otherwise, you might consider using `Collections.synchronizedList` to get a synchronized view of `myPersonId` and then doing all list operations through that synchronized view.  Note that you should not manipulate `myPersonId` directly in this case, but do all accesses solely through the list returned from the `Collections.synchronizedList` call.

Either way, you have to make sure that there can never be a situation where a read and a write or two writes could occur simultaneously to the same *unsynchronized* data structure.  Data structures documented as thread-safe or returned from `Collections.synchronizedList`, `Collections.synchronizedMap`, etc. are exceptions to this rule, so calls to those can be put anywhere. Non-synchronized data structures can still be used safely inside methods declared to be synchronized, however, because such methods are guaranteed by the JVM to never run at the same time, and therefore there could be no concurrent reading / writing.

Answer (score 0):

Java concurrency (multi-threading) :

Concurrency is the ability to run several programs or several parts of a program in parallel. If a time consuming task can be performed asynchronously or in parallel, this improve the throughput and the interactivity of the program.

We can do concurrent programming with Java. By java concurrency we can do parallel programming, immutability, threads, the executor framework (thread pools), futures, callables and the fork-join framework programmings.